# Binary Classification with Logistic Regression - Long Training Times

Tags: performance, machine-learning, optimization, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm relatively new to machine learning and am working on a binary classification problem using logistic regression. My dataset contains 500 rows and 7000 columns.
The first column represent the git changes and from the second columns onward the test name and its results.

| Changes | Test name 1 | Test name 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Change 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Change 2 | 1 | 0 |

I've transformed the git changes into a numerical vector (X), and the test case results are my target variable (y). I've split the dataset into a training set (80%) and a test set (20%).

The problem I'm encountering is that the training and prediction times are taking much longer than expected. For training, it's taking a considerable amount of time, and even prediction takes about 5 minutes. I'm wondering if this is normal for my dataset size or if there are ways to optimize my code for better performance.

Are the training and prediction times expected for this dataset size? Are there any optimizations I can make to speed up the process?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('final_filled.csv')

# Extract Git Changes column
git_changes = data.iloc[:, 0]

# Get all values from the first row starting from the second column
test_case_results = data.iloc[:, 1:]

# Initialize and fit the TF-IDF vectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
git_changes_tfidf_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(git_changes).toarray()
git_changes_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(git_changes_tfidf_vector)

# Getting Target variable into Y variable
y = test_case_results.values
X = git_changes_tfidf.values

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create a list to store binary logistic regression models
models = []

# Train a binary logistic regression model for each label
for i in range(y.shape[1]):
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train[:, i])
    models.append(model)

# Make predictions for each label
predictions = np.zeros_like(y_test)
for i, model in enumerate(models):
    predictions[:, i] = model.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the model
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying a one-vs-rest approach, where you're essentially training 7.000 different logistic regression models on your 500 data points.

I think this could result in significant overhead caused by initializing each model. You could look into using parallelization such that you can train some of the models concurrently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).